# How to enable the HTTP logs in Android?

Tags: android

I wrote a simple application and I am getting only those logs, I used `Log.i();`
I want the core logs (for example framework logs) how the httpclient, httpget, httppost, httprequest and httpresponse logs are sending and receiving data.

Please let me know if there is any procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, try this:
https://gist.github.com/cf23c4e184228a132390

Comment: Can't you just connect your phone to your laptop & run <code>adb logcat</code> ?

Comment: Thanks yar this is working , Will you please let me know how can i add for HttpRequest and HttpResponse as well

Comment: i tried using + "org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.level = FINEST\n"
                    + "org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.level = FINEST\n" but it is not working

Answer (score 3):

For latest api, using this code

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);

System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.headers", "debug");
```

and properties:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.wire VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.headers VERBOSE
```